# Get Weekstartdate and enddate by date

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to get `weekstartdate` and `weekenddate` by passing one `date` ?

When I pass `2016-07-27 01:24:10.510`, I need this output

startdate: `2016-07-24 00:00:00.000` which is `Sunday`
enddate: `2016-07-30 00:00:00.000` which is `Saturday`

I used this code, but this is returning wrong output

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = getdate()

SELECT  d.WeekStart,
    Weekend = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart) > StartOfNextMonth
                        THEN StartOfNextMonth
                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7, WeekStart)
                END
FROM    (   SELECT  WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY, 
                                    ((DATEPART(DAY, @Date) - 1) / 7.0) * 7, 
                                    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date), 0)),
                StartOfNextMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date) + 1, 0)
    ) AS d;
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could also be a Table-Valued Function

```
Declare @Date Date = GetDate()

Select weekstartdate = DateAdd(DD,1-DatePart(DW,@Date),@Date ) 
      ,weekenddate   = DateAdd(DD,7-DatePart(DW,@Date),@Date )
```

Returns

```
weekstartdate   weekenddate
2016-07-24      2016-07-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [`@@DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx) is `7`:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample DateTime );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values
  ( '2016-07-27 01:24:10.510' ),
  ( '2016-07-20 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-21 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-22 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-23 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-24 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-26 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-27 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-28 00:00:00.000' ),
  ( '2016-07-29 00:00:00.000' );

select Sample,
  DateAdd( day, 1 - DatePart( weekday, Sample ), Cast( Sample as Date ) ) as [StartOfWeek],
  DateAdd( day, 7 - DatePart( weekday, Sample ), Cast( Sample as Date ) ) as [EndOfWeek]
  from @Samples;
```